# How to insert a link programmatically into PDPushButton to existing pdf using pdfbox / acro-form

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

**The problem:**

I have a pdf that I've created using Adobe acrobat pro. Inside the pdf I have several form buttons ("fields") which I want to dynamically insert them a web url link to enter when one's click a button.

**what I've tried so far:**

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument.load(pdf);
PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
PDPushButton b1 = acroForm.getField("Button1");

PDActionURI uri = new PDActionURI();
uri.setURI("https://stackoverflow.com");

PDFormFieldAdditionalActions actions = new PDFormFieldAdditionalActions();
actions.setF(uri);

b1.setActions(actions);
```

**and -**

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument.load(pdf);
PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
PDPushButton b1 = acroForm.getField("Button1");

PDActionURI uri = new PDActionURI();
uri.setURI("https://stackoverflow.com");

b1.getWidget().setAction(uri);
```

I haven't find any documentation on how to do it - so I've tried the above code based on reading their open source code and what I've understood from it.

I've also tried to use an action called PDActionGoTo but it has a function 'setDestination' which gets 'PDDestination' object, but I didn't understand how to initial it with a url.

I've found also someone with a similar problem - only that he created the button in the code instead of getting it from the pdf file. I didn't manage to make the adjustment but I will supply the code (he wrote that it worked for him eventually):

```
PDPushButton pb = new PDPushButton(acroForm);
pb.setPartialName("sbtn");
COSDictionary cosPush = pb.getCOSObject();
COSDictionary cosA = new COSDictionary();
cosPush.setInt(COSName.F, 4);
cosPush.setItem(COSName.A, cosA);
cosPush.setItem(COSName.P, page);
cosA.setInt(COSName.FLAGS, 256);
cosA.setName(COSName.S, "SubmitForm");
COSDictionary cosF = new COSDictionary();
cosA.setItem(COSName.F, cosF);
cosF.setString(COSName.F, "https://stackoverflow.com");
cosF.setName("FS", "URL");
// add the field to the acroform
acroForm.getFields().add(pb);
```

*To see the original question go [here](https://pdfbox-users.markmail.org/message/i62xtxwqc4xhtwen?q=PDPushButton+action)*

Also, does anyone knows what are those constants COSName.F/COSName.A/ect. meaning? is it part of the pdf acro-form specification? I tried to look it up but didn't find any helpful information about it, beside that it looks like everyone that asked about pdfbox before somehow already knows it.

**about the environment:**

java 8

pdfbox version 2.0.22

adobe acrobat pro version 2022.001.20112

thanks for the help : )

Comment: You maybe right, however acrobat pro does give you the option to attach much more actions to a form button beside "submit a form". do you have an alternative to make a button which will redirect the user to a link? I need to first find the right button on the document, and when using a form-button is very easy to find.